# Scala API response JSON parser from JSON object

Tags: java, json, scala, dictionary, flatmap

I am new to Scala. I was trying to parse an API response in Scala. The API response is in the format:

```
{"items":[{"name":"john", "time":"2017-05-11T13:51:34.037232", "topic":"india", "reviewer":{"id":"12345","name":"jack"}}, 
          {"name":"Mary", "time":"2017-05-11T13:20:26.001496", "topic":"math", "reviewer":{"id":"5678","name":"Tom"}}]}
```

My target is to populate a list of reviewer id's from the JSON response. I tried to create a JSON object from the response by

```
val jsonObject= parse(jsonResponse.getContentString()).getOrElse(Json.empty)
```

but couldn't get the reviewer ids from the json object. Even tried to iterate the JSON object, but didn't work.

Comment: What is the parser you are using?

Comment: not any parser specifically. I tried 'play'

Comment: in your example it goes through a `parse` function, I would like to understand what that is. Or are you asking for a generic solution?

Comment: parse() supported by circe

Comment: I missed to add the import statement - import io.circe._

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with `circe` but here is how you would do it with `spray-json`

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

val jsonResponse = """{"items":[{"name":"john", "time":"2017-05-11T13:51:34.037232", "topic":"india", "reviewer":{"id":"12345","name":"jack"}},{"name":"Mary", "time":"2017-05-11T13:20:26.001496", "topic":"math", "reviewer":{"id":"5678","name":"Tom"}}]}"""
```

Need to define the schema using case classes:

```
case class Reviewer(id: String, name: String)
case class Item(name: String, time: String, topic: String, reviewer: Reviewer)
case class Items(items: Array[Item])
```

And their implicit conversion:

```
implicit val reviewerImp: RootJsonFormat[Reviewer] = jsonFormat2(Reviewer)
implicit val itemConverted: RootJsonFormat[Item] = jsonFormat4(Item)
implicit val itemsConverted: RootJsonFormat[Items] = jsonFormat1(Items)
```

Then it's very simple, parsing is just this:

```
val obj = jsonResponse.parseJson.convertTo[Items]
```

At last, get the ids for the reviewers:

```
val reviewers = obj.items.map(it => it.reviewer.id)
```

Comment: It gives me error at the import statements itself, like-
"Cannot resolve symbol spray" and "cannot resolve symbol DefaultJsonProtocol". Do I need to add some dependencies? Any clue?

Comment: Yes, you need `libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.3.3"`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned play, so here's how you could do it in Play

```
case class Reviewer(id:Long, name:String)
object Reviewer { implicit val format = Json.format[Reviewer] }
```

Once you have those set up you could either

```
val json:JsValue = Json.toJson(reviewerObject)
val json:JsObject = Json.toJson(reviewerObject).as[JsObject]
val json:String = Json.toJson(reviewerObject).toString // Valid json string
```

Or

```
val reviewer:Reviewer = Json.parse(reviewerJsonString).as[Reviewer]
val validates:Boolean = Json.parse(reviewerJsonString).validates[Reviewer]
```

Comment: object Reviewer { implicit val format = Json.format[Reviewer] } gives error - cannot resolve symbol 'format'. Json is circe Json ?

Comment: This would actually be for play.api.json.
As far as I can tell from their documentation it doesn't look like circe supports implicit marshalling from json to class ( only the reverse ), your best bet to get it into a class would be `val foo:Foo = decode[Foo](fooCompatibleJson)`. In reverse you would be able to do `foo.asJson`